# Need Help Debugging my Code That Reverses the Words in a String

Tags: c++, string

I need some help debugging my code. This code is intended to reverse the words in a string that is in the form of a sentence [assuming that the string does not have a "." at the end]. For some reason what I'm getting as an output is the indented output plus an extra space after the first word as well as the indented output minus the first word. I am a beginner at coding; so if possible, I would appreciate more simple to understand solutions, or a solution that uses a loop, strings, and arrays.

Sample Input:

```
My name is Edward
```

Intended Output:

```
Edward is name My
```

Output Received:

```
Edward  is name
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string s, n, a;
getline(cin, s);

for (int i = s.length(); i >= 0; i--){
    if (s[i] != 32 ) {
        n += s[i];
    }
    else {
        for (int j = n.length() -1; j >= 0; j--){
            a += n[j];
        }
        cout << a << ' ';
        n.clear();
        a.clear();
    }
}

cin.ignore();
getchar();
return 0;

}
```

Also, I just noticed that there is also an extra space at the end. If there is a way to maybe cancel outputting the last space; please tell me.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You want to reverse words (`std::string` variables) not chars!

Comment: `s[s.length()]` is out of range which is what your outer loop starts with.  It's undefined behavior, but in my test it makes `n` have a null as the first character and then that gets copied around, etc.  A debugger would help you quite a bit, allowing you to step through each line and see how the operations affect your variables.

Comment: If you fix the out of bounds error in the outer loop your code mostly works.  The problem is your `else` that reverses the word and prints it out won't get hit for the last word unless it ends with a space.  Consider breaking the inner loop into its own function you can call with `n` outside the loop to process the final word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks for the help from the comments and answers, I fixed the problem with the extra space and added something at the end that outputs the final word. It's not perfect, but it works. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string s, n;
getline(cin, s);

for (int i = s.length() -1; i >= 0; i--){
if (s[i] != 32) {
    n += s[i];
}
else {
    for (int j = n.length() -1; j >= 0; j--){
        cout << n[j];
    }
    cout << ' ';
    n.clear();
}
}

for (int k = n.length() -1 ; k >= 0; k--)
cout << n[k];

cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in my comment, you're reversing the whole string by characters, but you need to split up for words and reverse:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s, n;
    getline(cin, s);
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::vector<string> words;
    while(iss >> n) {
        words.push_back(n);
    }

    std::reverse(words.begin(),words.end());

    for(auto word : words) {
        std::cout << word << ' ';
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;    

}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/MpZwoz)

Answer (score 2):

So this is really just an additional step of abstraction from [πάντα ῥεῖ's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335924/2642059). You can use [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to further simplify your code.

The entire code to answer your question can be boiled down to:

```
const vector<string> words{ istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>() };

copy(crbegin(words), crend(words), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/uKwkTp)

Comment: I'm so sorry about lacking votes for today.  _"πάντα ῥεῖ's excellent answer"_ makes me blush, thank you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ LOL, I love to see good C++ answers. I like to upvote them and reference them wherever possible... I just wish I saw more *code* that looked like your and my answer :J

Answer (score -1):

you can use `strrev();` function instead all of your `for` block.